# Can One touch handled by Two UIViews?

Tags: iphone, uiview

Say, I've two overlapping UIView layers:

```
----view-top
  --view-below
```

When I touch the screen, I want the touch be handled by these two views, not just one.

How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried to do it? how are you handling touch? touchesBegan/... or gesture recognizers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

This will send the touch to the next responder in the chain, in this case, your view!